# Update the code for a Bitbucket pull request (Mercurial)

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket, pull-request

I want to update a pull request created on a Mercurial (hg) Bitbucket repository with new code. Is this possible?

I tried `hg push -f` on the branch, but it created a new head and the old one still exists. The PR still points to the previous commit.

Is there any way from the web UI to point the existing PR to a new head?

Answer (score 0):

This is abnormal, because it works without `hg push -f`.

Just doing `hg push --branch name_of_pull_request_branch_of_harald` should be enough.

Now, you could try to edit your pull request using the BitBucket website. Use the **Edit** button, between the **Merge** and **Decline** buttons, there you can select the updated branch.

Answer (score 0):

To update a pull request in bitbucket, all you need to do is push an additional commit to the branch the pull request is for in your fork.

In your case, it sounds like you need to merge the new head with the one the pull request is pointing to and then push that to your fork. This should update the pull request with whatever you've changed.